# exception handling for wicket panels?

Tags: exception, wicket, panels

I added exception handling for the pages, now I want to do it for the panels.

I found http://apache-wicket.1842946.n4.nabble.com/ExceptionHandling-in-Panels-td3311271.html and http://apache-wicket.1842946.n4.nabble.com/newbie-best-practice-for-not-rendering-component-td1871632.html, but the answers are not satisfying as I realized that there is no built-in support in Wicket for exception handling for panels as there is for pages. And choosing between a fragment with the panel markup and an error fragment is not the robust support I'm looking for.
Since most of the exceptions in my web app can rise in the section of the logic where the components are added and models are used, I thought of placing that part of the logic in the constructor, so when an error occurs, I could catch it and then show the error panel I want. Something like:

```
try{
  add(new MyPanel(panelId, model));
}catch (Exception e){
  add(new ErrorPanel(panelId, e));
  ... 
}
```

But I get warnings when resolving properties in the constructor by using the getString() method.
So, my questions are:
- Is there any online example where this has been solved? Or any idea about that?
- If using the getString() in the constructor throws that type of warnings, what would the best practice then?
- I I can't place that logic in the constructor, because you are not supposed to resolve properties there, what options are there besides the one I mentioned?

Comment: So basically you want to replace one panel with another?

Answer (score 2):

As with most logic in panels, the constructor isn't the best place. During construction-time, the panel (or any other component) isn't yet attaced to a page. That leaves the component in a fragile state where some components don't even have any markup.
More complex logic should be placed outside of the constructor. Wicket 1.5 offers an onInitialRender method that can be overridden where one can safely put any logic. In Wicket 1.4.x there is an easy way to simulate that hook by implementing onBeforeRender as

```
@Override
protected void onBeforeRender() {
    if (!hasBeenRendered()) {
        onInitialRender();
    }
    super.onBeforeRender();
}
```

thus creating an onInitialRender-hook that's only executed once and IMO the best place to put any logic that's not dependent on other hooks.

Edit: In your case the warning indicated that the intended chain of Resource-Lookups can't be used since the is no hierarchy of components that can be used as fallbacks if the resource isn't found at the current component or final application level.

Comment: @CarlosP could you explain, why you un-accepted the answer after two years?

Comment: This usually happens when a new answer appears, OP thinks it's a good idea to tick the checkmark on that answer too, realizes the mistake, unticks it and leaves the page without reticking the checkmark on the original answer. (Thanks for your answer though, helped me a lot.)

Answer (score 1):

Note: Wicket 1.5 does not offer an onInitialRender method (it was probably added and removed during some pre-releases). Instead, the onInitialize method should be used for adding child components to the panel (or any other component).

see https://cwiki.apache.org/WICKET/migration-to-wicket-15.html#MigrationtoWicket1.5-ComponentInitializationComponent%2523onInitialize for details.